# Java: XML to Object and Object to XML with properties

Tags: java, xml, properties, jaxb

I have a not-little problem with my current project, and probably you can help me with this...

When I worked before with xml messages, marshalling converted java objects to xml, where the java object attributes were set to xml nodes. But now I need to set that object attributes to xml node attributes, as I show here:

```
<Identification_List counter="">
   <Identification number="XXXXXXX" letter="X" name="PERSON">
      <TravelList counter="">
          <Travel travelType="">
      </TravelList>
   </Identification>
</Identification_List>
```

How can I do this? What framework should I use? Thank you!

Edit: Example java class:

```
public class Identification {
  private int number;
  private char letter;
  private String name;
  private List<Travel> travelList;

  //Add here constructors, getters and setters
}
```

That java class is the one that should be marshalled, where number, letter and name are the xml object properties

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you mean. If you are using JAXB, then use the [`@XmlAttribute` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) to map Java object properties to XML attributes.

Comment: So, @XmlAttribute annotation adds attributes to a xml node, but what should I use if i want to add attributes and nodes to that xml node?

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly your question is. Can you clarify it? Show the code of your Java class(es) and what the corresponding XML should look like, and explain more clearly what properties in the Java class you want to map to what attributes or elements in XML.

Comment: I know it's hard to understand my question, I just need to know how can I marshall my java object into their expected xml structure, every xml i have converted before had no node properties, instead of that, my xml had this structure:
<Identification>
  <Number>XXXXXX</Number>
  <Letter>X</Letter>
  <Name>PERSON</Name>
  <TravelList>
    <Travel>
      <TravelType>XXXX</TravelType>
    </Travel>
  </TravelList>
</Identification>

And I don't really know how to do this :(

Btw, I edited the post with the origin java class that should be mapped to the expected XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the appropriate JAXB annotations to your classes, to tell JAXB how to map your class to XML. For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Identification_List")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IdentificationList {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int counter;

    @XmlElement(name = "Identification")
    private List<Identification> identifications;

    // getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Identification {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int number;

    @XmlAttribute
    private char letter;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "TravelList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Travel")
    private List<Travel> travels;

    // getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Travel {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String travelType;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to convert java to xml ? use the same library ,

Here an Example

1-IdentificationList Class

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;


@XmlRootElement(name = "Identification_List")

public class IdentificationList {

    private int counter;
    private List<Identification> identificationList;

    public IdentificationList() {
    }

    public IdentificationList(List<Identification> identificationList) {
        this.identificationList = identificationList;
        this.counter = identificationList == null ? 0 : identificationList.size();
        ;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Identification")
    public List<Identification> getIdentificationList() {
        return identificationList;
    }

    public void setIdentificationList(List<Identification> identificationList) {
        this.identificationList = identificationList;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
}
```

2-Identification Class

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;






@XmlType(propOrder = {"number", "letter", "name","travelList"})
public class Identification {


    private int number;

    private String letter;

    private String name;

    private TravelList travelList;


    public Identification() {
    }

    public Identification(int number, String letter, String name, TravelList travelList) {
        this.number = number;
        this.letter = letter;
        this.name = name;
        this.travelList = travelList;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
     @XmlAttribute
    public String getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public void setLetter(String letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }
     @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @XmlElement(name = "TravelList")
    public TravelList getTravelList() {
        return travelList;
    }

    public void setTravelList(TravelList travelList) {
        this.travelList = travelList;
    }
}
```

3-TravelList Class

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.List;


public class TravelList {


    private List<Travel>travels;
    private int counter;

    public TravelList() {
    }

    public TravelList(List<Travel> travels) {
        this.travels = travels;
        this.counter=travels==null?0:travels.size();
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "Travel")
    public List<Travel> getTravels() {
        return travels;
    }

    public void setTravels(List<Travel> travels) {
        this.travels = travels;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
}
```

4-Travel Class

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;


public class Travel {

    private String travelType;

    public Travel() {
    }

    public Travel(String travelType) {
        this.travelType = travelType;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getTravelType() {
        return travelType;
    }

    public void setTravelType(String travelType) {
        this.travelType = travelType;
    }
}
```

5-IdentificationToXML Class

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class IdentificationToXML {


    public static void main(String ...args) throws  Exception {


        JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(IdentificationList.class);

        Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();
        marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Travel travel1=new Travel("My First Travel");
        Travel travel2=new Travel("My Second Travel");


        Travel travel3=new Travel("My Third Travel");
        Travel travel4=new Travel("My Fourth Travel");


        ArrayList<Travel> list=new ArrayList<Travel>();
        list.add(travel1);
        list.add(travel2);



        ArrayList<Travel> list2=new ArrayList<Travel>();
        list2.add(travel3);
        list2.add(travel4);

        Identification identification1=new Identification(111,"c","My Name",new TravelList(list));
        Identification identification2=new Identification(222,"d","My Name",new TravelList(list2));
        ArrayList<Identification> list3=new ArrayList<Identification>();
        list3.add(identification1);
        list3.add(identification2);
        IdentificationList identification=new IdentificationList(list3);

        marshallerObj.marshal(identification, new FileOutputStream("identification.xml"));
    }
}
```

6-Output :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Identification_List counter="2">
        <Identification number="111" letter="c" name="My Name">
            <TravelList counter="2">
                <Travel travelType="My First Travel"/>
                <Travel travelType="My Second Travel"/>
            </TravelList>
        </Identification>
        <Identification number="222" letter="d" name="My Name">
            <TravelList counter="2">
                <Travel travelType="My Third Travel"/>
                <Travel travelType="My Fourth Travel"/>
            </TravelList>
        </Identification>
    </Identification_List>
```